# How to find out the max value of the third field according to the first two fields using awk

Tags: shell, awk

The file content is as follows:

```
333379266       834640619       88
333379280       834640621       99
333379280       834640621       66
333376672       857526666       99
333376672       857526666       78
333376672       857526666       62
```

The first two columns may be duplicate, and I want to output the first two columns and the corresponding max value of the third column.In this case,The **result file**  should be as follows:

```
333379266       834640619       88
333379280       834640621       99
333376672       857526666       99
```

My attemp is:

`awk '{d[$1" "$2]=$3;if ($3>=d[$1" "$2]){num[$1" "$2]=$3} else{num[$1" "$2]=d[$1" "$2]} }END{for(i in num) print i,num[i]}'`

But it does not work,because `$3>=d[$1" "$2]` is always right , the value of num is always `$3`, and `awk` reads the file line by line,so the value of `num` is always the last one,not the max one.

I'll be appreciated if anyone can give me the solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  array[$1,$2]=array[$1,$2]>$3?array[$1,$2]:$3
}
END{
  for(i in array){
    print i,array[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Issues with OP's code:***

On your line `d[$1" "$2]=$3;if ($3>=d[$1" "$2])`; since you are assigning array d's value  before comparison to current line's 3rd field so your this condition is always going to be true is what I could see major issue in OP's attempt.

***OP's attempt fix:*** IMHO my solution above should be good but trying to fix OP's attempt here.

```
awk '{if ($3>=d[$1" "$2]){num[$1" "$2]=$3} else{num[$1" "$2]=d[$1" "$2]};d[$1" "$2]=$3}END{for(i in num) print i,num[i]}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This one liner applied the same idea as your codes, the only difference is, using `FS` instead of space.

```
awk '{k=$1FS$2;a[k]=a[k]>$NF?a[k]:$NF}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
```

Comment: I find the output of the first field is not the order of the file,the first column of the output is: `333379280->333379266->333376672`, while the first column of original file is: `333379266->333379280->333376672`

Comment: Can you explain t to me if it is convenient to you.Thanks.

Comment: @xoyabc If we talk about the order, your codes in the question, the accepted answer, and mine, they are the same. If you used `for ( i in array)` the order is not preserved. If you want to ensure the order to be the same as the input file, you should handle it manually. E.g. create another array only for order.